# String to ArrayList with HashMAP

Tags: java, android, json, list, arraylist

I have a string `[{Label_0=Mobile, Phone_0=+212131231}]`, stored in `ArrayList` within `HashMap`, I need to assign it to another `Arraylist` to fetch values but getting a syntax error

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> phonesArr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> phoneDict = new HashMap<String, String>();

    phoneDict.put(String.format("Label_%d", locali1),PTYPE);
    phoneDict.put(String.format("Phone_%d", locali1),phoneNumber);

   phonesArr.add(phoneDict);
```

There is a reason why I am storing it in a array because phone Numbers can be multiple for one contacts.

```
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> _allPeoplesDictArr = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            HashMap<String, String> personDict = new HashMap<String, String>();

            personDict.put("PhoneNumbers", phonesArr.toString())    //// Value stored as array to string
                                               // [{Label_0=Mobile, Phone_0=+212131231}]

           _allPeoplesDictArr.add(personDict);


                for (int j = 0; j < _allPeoplesDictArr.size(); j++) {
                        String localPhoneStr = _allPeoplesDictArr.get(j)
                                .get("PhoneNumbers");
                        Log.d("localPhoneStr", localPhoneStr);      ///  I dont want to retrieve it as string      

                        List<HashMap<String, String>> localPhoneArr = _allPeoplesDictArr.get(j).get("PhoneNumbers");        //// I  want to retrieve it as array but getting syntax error.


                        if (localPhoneArr.size() > 0) {

                            for (int k = 0; k < localPhoneArr.size(); k++) {

                                HashMap<String, String> userDict = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                userDict.put(
                                        "label",
                                        localPhoneArr.get(k).get(
                                                String.format("Label_%d", k)));
                                userDict.put(
                                        "value",
                                        localPhoneArr.get(k).get(
                                                String.format("Phone_%d", k)));


                            }
                        }
                }


            I am getting syntax error at grabing values  that is now as a JSON `[{Label_0=Mobile, Phone_0=+212131231}]`

                List<HashMap<String, String>> localPhoneArr = _allPeoplesDictArr.get(j).get("PhoneNumbers");
```

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you'd show a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem. We don't know the type of `_allPeoplesDictArr` at the moment, for example.

Comment: Is `_allPeoplesDictArr` now a List<String> or a List<HashMap<String, String>>? Because you have `String localPhoneStr = _allPeoplesDictArr.get(j).get("PhoneNumbers");` and `List<HashMap<String, String>> localPhoneArr = _allPeoplesDictArr.get(j).get("PhoneNumbers");`

Comment: I have updated my question for better understanding  _allPeoplesDictArr.get(j).get("PhoneNumbers");      this contains arraylist with Hash but I am unable to retrives its values.

Comment: @super-qua  I know it is HashMap<String, String> instead of HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, String>>>,  but I isnt there any way to rectify my problem with the current assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `List<HashMap<String, String>> localPhoneArr = _allPeoplesDictArr.get(j).get("PhoneNumbers");` is giving you the syntax error, because it is a `String`. If you want to make an `Array` out of it, you have to parse the JSON String. You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)

It should look something like this

```
String localPhoneStr = _allPeoplesDictArr.get(j).get("PhoneNumbers");
JSONArray phoneArray = new JSONArray(localPhoneStr);

for(int i=0; i<phoneArray.length(); i++){

    JSONObject phone = phoneArray.getJSONObject(i);

    userDict.put("label", phone.getString(String.format("Label_%d", i)));
    userDict.put("value", phone.getString(String.format("Phone_%d", i)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mate for the logic as I like it , I will try and hoping that it will work as per my needs.

Comment: A small modification required as userDict.put("label", phone.getString(String.format("Label_%d", i)));
    userDict.put("value", phone.getString(String.format("Phone_%d", i)));

Comment: Glad it helped you. I updated the answer to include your modifications for others to see them